# Sn74ls47N chip not working in this setup

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

So for electronic engineering we have to make a basic bcd to decimal decoder, and an Sn74ls47N was provided as a decoder, and the 7seg being like any other standard 7seg. Me and my buddy have it wired correctly according to the diagram given in class, but the circuit shows a negative symbol (led segment g) constantly lit up, and sometimes lights up an 8 when you press the 4 button. Any insight would be appreciated since we are beginners. Ty in advance.[image][image]

Comment: We have no idea how you wired that stuff. Show a schematic.

Comment: 1) As PlasmaHH says: include a schematic, a photo of a breadboard does not suffice. Yes it is so important that I mention the same thing again 2) start **measuring**, start by checking that the supply voltages are correct.

Comment: I don't see any capacitors in there either... esp for that regulator.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize that the top ground rail and the bottom ground rail are not connected... The bottom one (one on the left) is connected to the negative of the battery, but the top one (one on the right) doesn't seem to be connected to any type of ground or negative.

Comment: @RonBeyer doesn't he have 9V and 5V on the right, ground on the left. Assuming that is like a 7805 at the top. OF course his choice of green wires for Vcc is confusing.

Comment: @Trevor Shouldn't the 9V ground connect with the 5V ground? I only see the positive 9V going to the regulator, the ground should be there too.

Comment: @RonBeyer centre pin of the 7805 goes to ground.

Comment: @Trevor I guess the confusion is that he is using the negative rail on the top as +5V, the Positive rail on the top as +9V, and the positive rail on the bottom as ground...

Comment: We need to see the schematic. If it's really telling you to pull inputs to ground via a 120 Ohm resistor and an LED, and telling you to omit the current limiting resistors on the outputs, I can only assume this course module is titled "How not to use the 7447".

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that the voltage at the inputs on the 'LS47 is too high.  In the photo, it looks like you have LEDs in series with the pull-down resistors. The voltage drop across a red LED can be around 1.5V, even at low current. TTL inputs need to be pulled to 0.8V or below for a valid logic zero.  Try it with only the pull-down resistors, without the LEDs in series.

Comment: I know what you mean (I think!) but just to be clear to the OP - your suggestion to "Try it without the LEDs" does not mean to just unplug and remove the LEDs, because then the pull-down resistors would be left disconnected from the switches. You're suggesting to connect the pull-down resistors directly between ground and each switch (without an LED in series) as shown on the schematic, right? (+1 anyway, as I'm fairly sure that's what you mean.)

Comment: @SamGibson  Yes, that is what I had in mind.  Hope my edit makes that more clear

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual question, so here's some insight.

Since you are apparently studying electrical engineering, you need to learn to debug circuits.  Us telling you the problem will not help you.

When a circuit doesn't work, a good first step is to use a multimeter to determine if what you *think* is connected actually is, and if the voltages at various places are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 2):

Bipolar TTL (74LSxx) inputs source current, so when not connected will be seen as a logic High.  You need to draw 1 mA or more from the input to make it a logic Low.

It appears that your switches are pulling the inputs High when pressed. Since the inputs are "naturallly" High, this won't work.

Traditionally, we would put the switches between input and Ground, to ensure a Low, with a 3K or higher resistor from the input pin to Vcc to ensure a High with the  switch off.

The inputs on CMOS parts (74HC, 74AC) are very high impedance - do not source or sink any significant current - so they can be used with a switch between the input pin and either Vcc or Ground, with a 5K or higher resistor to the other supply rail.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, thanks for everyones insights and responses,
We showed it to the prof and they said it should work, gave us a cd4055 chip to use instead, and it worked perfectly. Thanks anyways all!